# Bootstrap table not populating with data from server

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to set up pagination using the following: http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/index.html

So far, I have the HTML table appearing on my page, and I can also see from the Network tab in the F12 tools that the server side code is being called, and json data is being returned.  But I don't know how to get the data to appear inside the table.  Right now, the table just says: no matching records found.

Here's my HTML code:  http://jsfiddle.net/pdwjq9e9/2/

And the server is returning this:

```
{'id':1,'name':'test name','code':'12345','available':'yes'}
```

I'm not sure how to get the data to appear in the table. 
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

As as a test, I tried to change the server side code to return this instead of json:

```
    "<tr><td>1</td><td>Test Name</td><td>12345</td><td>yes</td></tr>"
```

And in the networking section of F12 tool, in the response to my GET, I can see that it's returning the HTML. But it doesn't fill the table in question with this html.

**EDIT 2**

In F12, under networking, I am noticing that there are two separate requests being made.  One is for the main page, let's say it's called index.html.  That renders the page in general.  Then I see a separate request being made that looks like this:

http://testdev/cgi-bin/widgets?order=asc&limit=10&offset=0

And in the response tab for that request, I see:

```
{'total':1, 'rows':[{'id':1,'name':'test name','code':'12345','available':'yes'}]}
```

(Notice that I've changed the format of the json data to include total records, as a part of testing)

Also, in the bootstrap table example page, I don't see anywhere where they iterate through a json result set via javascript or ajax to populate the table.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: This really has nothing to do with Bootstrap, which only applies styling and pagination. Your server-side app needs to generate the table HTML.

Comment: Also, the JSFiddle TidyUp button is your friend. :-)

Comment: @isherwood, please see my Edit 1 - my attempt to do what you've suggested.

Comment: Maybe I misspoke. Your server should return JSON, but you need to write something to load that data into the table. To my knowledge, Bootstrap doesn't have a mechanism to do that. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @isherwood,  as far as this code having nothing to do with bootstrap, i'm not quite sure I agree. I understand boostrap has to do with layout / styling but the tables plug-in and their examples are all about rigging your html up to a back end for pagination. No?

Comment: @isherwood ok, your last comment makes more sense to me.  and I guess i've been reviewing their sample code: https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table-examples/blob/master/welcome.html but I can't see where they do it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77324/discussion-between-dot-and-isherwood).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you believe it if i told you it was because of single quotes instead of double quotes in my json data?

I changed

```
{'total':1, 'rows':[{'id':1,'name':'test name','code':'12345','available':'yes'}]}
```

to

```
{"total":1, "rows":[{"id":1,"name":"test name","code":"12345","available":"yes"}]}
```

My bad.  I should have used jsonlint sooner to validate what I was sending back.